# Two square plots that fill one sheet of paper

Tags: r, plot

I would like to place two square plots on one page and have the resulting figure fill most of one sheet of paper.  This seems like a very basic idea.  However, the default seems to be to create rectangular plots.  When I specify that the plots be square their size becomes quite small relative to the page.  If I succeed in getting the square plots larger the axis labels become hidden.  I have tried numerous variations of `omi` and `mar` and `layout` without success.

I would like to use base `R`.  Thank you for any advice.

```
setwd('c:/users/markm/simple R programs')

x <- 1:10
y1.1 <- x ^2
y1.2 <- x + 50
y1.3 <- x ^1.5

pdf("plots_June1_2015.pdf")

par(mfrow=c(2,1))

     plot(x, y1.1, type = 'l', col = 'black' , lwd = 1, lty = 1,
          xlab = 'My X Axis',
          ylab = 'My Y Axis')
          lines(x, y1.2, type = 'l', col = 'black' , lwd = 1, lty = 2)
          lines(x, y1.3, type = 'l', col = 'black' , lwd = 1, lty = 3)
     title('Plot One')

     plot(x, y1.1, type = 'l', col = 'black' , lwd = 1, lty = 1,
          xlab = 'My X Axis',
          ylab = 'My Y Axis')
          lines(x, y1.2, type = 'l', col = 'black', lwd = 1, lty = 2)
          lines(x, y1.3, type = 'l', col = 'black', lwd = 1, lty = 3)
     title('Plot Two')

dev.off()
```

Below are various unsuccessful attempts:

```
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), mar=c(3,3,3,3), cex.lab=0.75, pty="s", cex.axis=0.75)
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), mar=c(3,3,3,3), cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75)
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(1,1,1,1), mar=c(3,3,3,3), cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75)
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(1,1,1,1), cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75)
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(1,1,1,1), cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75, pty="s")
#par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(1,1,1,1), cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75, asp=1)
#par(mfrow=c(2,1))
#layout(matrix(c(1,1), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(3,1), heights=c(1,2))
#layout(matrix(c(2,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(3,1), heights=c(1,2))
#layout(matrix(c(2,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(1,1), heights=c(1,1))
#layout(matrix(c(2,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(1,1), heights=c(1,1))
#layout(matrix(c(2,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), widths=lcm(7,7), heights=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're focusing on the wrong issue. The final size is defined by your `pdf` call, not `par`. Using

```
pdf("plots_June1_2015.pdf", width = 11.69, height = 16.53)
```

(11.69 x 16.53 is the A3 sheet size in inches [according to Google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=a3%20width%20and%20height%20))

And the unchanged code you posted I got (this is a printscreen from the pdf)

[image]